# Tikkun haklali in English vs. Hebrew

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, tikkunim

Rabbi Alon Anava says that reading the Tikun Haklali in Hebrew is a 1000 times more powerful than English. But my question is, what if I pronounce the Hebrew wrong? Does that disqualify my reading from being accepted in heaven?

Comment: Prayers don't require perfect pronunciation. There are multiple sources saying that angels fix the mispronunciations, and that Hashem cherishes prayers if meant well even if they are mistakenly pronounced in a way that would have totally heretical meanings. That said, praying in English is fine for most things. (As a side point, if you're looking for someone to guide you in a spiritual journey, I would absolutely not recommend listening to Alon Anava. Lots of red flags.  Try Tovia Singer,  Manis Friedman, YY Jacobson, Paysach Krohn, or one of the many other wonderful Jewish role models.)

Comment: When I asked a similar question I was told by my rabbi 'Imagine the pride a father feels when his son starts to read and stumbles to over the letters he's reading. That's how Hashem feels when a Baal teshuva struggles to pronounce Hebrew in prayers and learning.'